# kettle7.1 connect to mysql ERROR The driver has not received any packets from the server

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, kettle, pdi

I'm studying Pentaho Data Integration 7.1 to connect to MySQL, but I got the error as follows:

```
Error connecting to database [1] :org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occurred while trying to connect to the database

Error connecting to database: (using class org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver)
Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.


org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occurred while trying to connect to the database

Error connecting to database: (using class org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver)
Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.


at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:472)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:370)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:341)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:331)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseFactory.getConnectionTestReport(DatabaseFactory.java:80)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseMeta.testConnection(DatabaseMeta.java:2783)
at org.pentaho.ui.database.event.DataHandler.testDatabaseConnection(DataHandler.java:597)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulDomContainer.invoke(AbstractXulDomContainer.java:313)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:157)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:141)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swt.tags.SwtButton.access$500(SwtButton.java:43)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swt.tags.SwtButton$4.widgetSelected(SwtButton.java:137)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:820)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:796)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.xul.KettleDialog.show(KettleDialog.java:80)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.xul.KettleDialog.show(KettleDialog.java:47)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.dialog.XulDatabaseDialog.open(XulDatabaseDialog.java:116)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.dialog.DatabaseDialog.open(DatabaseDialog.java:60)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.trans.step.BaseStepDialog.showDbDialogUnlessCancelledOrValid(BaseStepDialog.java:779)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.trans.step.BaseStepDialog$EditConnectionListener.widgetSelected(BaseStepDialog.java:1425)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.trans.steps.tableinput.TableInputDialog.open(TableInputDialog.java:436)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.delegates.SpoonStepsDelegate.editStep(SpoonStepsDelegate.java:127)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.editStep(Spoon.java:8766)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.trans.TransGraph.editStep(TransGraph.java:3217)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.trans.TransGraph.mouseDoubleClick(TransGraph.java:783)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.readAndDispatch(Spoon.java:1366)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.waitForDispose(Spoon.java:8022)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.start(Spoon.java:9277)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.main(Spoon.java:692)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:92)
Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error connecting to database: (using class org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver)
Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:585)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:456)
... 55 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:407)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1116)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:346)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2334)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2371)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2163)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:794)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:407)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:378)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:305)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:567)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:244)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:254)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:295)
    ... 71 more

Hostname       :1
Port           :3306
Database name  :127.0.0.1
```

I've changed a lot of MySQL driver versions such as
[So many versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnAjm.png)

And the port 3306 is opening, server is localhost.

The configuration of 'data-integration\simple-jndi\jdbc.properties' file is as follows

```
SampleData/type=javax.sql.DataSource
SampleData/driver=org.h2.Driver
SampleData/url=jdbc:h2:file:samples/db/sampledb;IFEXISTS=TRUE
SampleData/user=PENTAHO_USER
SampleData/password=PASSWORD
Quartz/type=javax.sql.DataSource
Quartz/driver=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
Quartz/url=jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/quartz
Quartz/user=pentaho_user
Quartz/password=password
Hibernate/type=javax.sql.DataSource
Hibernate/driver=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
Hibernate/url=jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/hibernate
Hibernate/user=hibuser
Hibernate/password=password
Shark/type=javax.sql.DataSource
Shark/driver=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
Shark/url=jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/shark
Shark/user=sa
Shark/password=
PDI_Operations_Mart/type=javax.sql.DataSource
PDI_Operations_Mart/driver=org.postgresql.Driver
PDI_Operations_Mart/url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hibernate?searchpath=pentaho_operations_mart
PDI_Operations_Mart/user=hibuser
PDI_Operations_Mart/password=password
live_logging_info/type=javax.sql.DataSource
live_logging_info/driver=org.postgresql.Driver
live_logging_info/url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hibernate?searchpath=pentaho_dilogs
live_logging_info/user=hibuser
live_logging_info/password=password
Mysql/type=javax.sql.DataSource
Mysql/driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
Mysql/url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql
Mysql/username=root
Mysql/password=root
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: _"Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect"_ Are you using Windows? Can you ping localhost from the command prompt, have you tried running the network troubleshooter?

Comment: I've tried Ping and telnet on 3306 ； It's connected, but it can't connect Mysql in kettle 7.1；I have changed many versions of the mysql driver and still can't connect. The above is the error message